# Lightning Web Component Action not showing up on community page

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata-api, quickaction

I've been having this issue where I created a LWC to act as an action, and while it shows up fine on the record page, I'm having some issues having it show up on my Community App. At first I thought it was something to do with my meta-data, but I went through and added it, but it doesn't seem to have helped - I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing.

Here's my meta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
       <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
       <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
       <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
     <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
   </targetConfig>
   <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
    <property name="recordId" type="String" default="{!recordId}" />
  </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

And here's the issue -
[image]

[image]

Please let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the release notes that delivered this feature [Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_quick_actions.htm&type=5&release=232)

> This change applies to Lightning Experience desktop in Developer, Enterprise, Essentials, Professional, and Unlimited editions. Quick actions aren’t available in Experience Cloud sites.

I think you need to call lwc from aura then display in Experience Cloud sites